# Finding the shortest path to solve colored water sorting games

Tags: python, numpy, graph-theory, breadth-first-search, game-theory

So my aunt plays this now popular mobile game, shown in the picture below. She got stuck on a certain level and asked me if I can solve it. Knowing that I'm not smart enough to find patterns or a strategy to solve it, and knowing only the basics in Python, I thought I should try to solve it by writing a script, and that it's the perfect opportunity to learn new stuff, I started my journey of 2 weeks.

[image: game example]

The game consists of a number of bottles, full with layers of different colored bottles, and generally one or two empty bottles, and the goal is to make all bottles uniformly colored. A move consists of taking a bottle full of at least on layer and pouring it in another bottle. Main rules are you can pour any color in an empty bottle, and you only can pour a layer on another layer if they are the same color.

My first approach to solving it, was by creating a new `class bottle`, implemented all the rules in it, which means because I knew only the basics, it took me a lot of time and it was really not optimized (I didn't know about stacks and had to write down so many `if.. elif.. else` statements to specify when a bottle can pour in another bottle). After I finished that I tried to write some code that can solve it. I didn't have many ideas on how the code would know which bottle to pick and where to pour it, so I went for the easy solution: pick them randomly. And it solved it instantly (kinda) for a small number of bottles, last one I tried was with 10 bottles, but with 15 bottles or more, it couldn't.

So then my second thought was maybe calculating every single possibility and move, i.e. make the game tree, and then use a search algorithm to find the shortest path, i read a bit about game trees and graph's searching algorithms and decided to use a breadth-first search(afterwards I learned that the graph I work with is a directed acyclic graph, so it's better to work with topological sorting, I'm not sure tho). The nodes in the game tree are the different states the bottles are in after pouring them in each other, and the edges are the moves that get you from one state to another. Here is how I generated the game tree in somewhat of a pseudocode:

```
take the first bottle A
create a list of bottles, list A, that bottle A can pour in
for each bottle B in list A, we pour bottle A in bottle B, and get a new state of bottles C
check if state C is already a node in the graph, or a permutation of a node(see explanation after the code) and add it to the graph if not
do what we did to bottle A, to all other bottles in the current node
then move to the children nodes and do the same
```

What I meant by checking permutations of a node is, for example, (bottle(1,2,1), bottle(0,0,0), bottle(2,1,2)) would be different from (bottle(1,2,1), bottle(2,1,2), bottle(0,0,0)), so when I left the permutations in, graphs that would have just 3000 nodes get as big as 200000 nodes.

The problem with the code I wrote was that it takes too much time to generate the game tree, last time I tried, it took 5 hours to generate the game tree for a 16 bottles level, which I think is a lot, and it can be done much much faster. A friend of mine suggested using Numpy, so each state or node in the graph would be a single matrix, and because Numpy can do things much much faster, it might be the way to do it, but me not being savvy at Numpy, I thought I can ask here for general good practices that can help me solve my problem, e.g. how to make checking if the node is already on the graph, or if a permutation of it, in this case, it would be checking if two matrices are equivalent up to permutation of columns or something like that.

So my question would be: how would you solve this if you were on my shoes, and how do you think I can get my code better optimized? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to get rid of trying to brute force every possible set of moves. This is O(n!) and will become unreasonable *very* quickly.

Comment: For this I would consider investigating the A* search algorithm. A candidate for fitness function could be the number of layers that are combined. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

Comment: You could check out [Raymond Hettinger's  presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_GP9OpZPUYc&t=435s) on puzzle solvers.

Answer (score 6):

Very interesting problem! I do have some suggestions

- Firstly in my opinion searching a huge configuration tree like this without a clear idea where you're going is at best inefficient. Why not prefer "directions" that lead to more bottles being filled or filled more highly in the same color. See my `__iter__` below.
- I think it could be worthwhile to recognize two states of the puzzle to be the same if the bottles only vary in order. You could do that by having the colors in the bottles represented by tuples of integers and saving a set of those (since the set does not safe the order).  See `set_rep` below.

I couldn't resist to code this up. As a basis I have used Raymond Hettinger's [Generic Puzzle Solver.](https://rhettinger.github.io/puzzle.html)
 Especially my `solve` method is strongly influenced by his.

#### The actual code

```
import numpy as np
from collections import deque


class ColoredWater:
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.pos = pos

    @staticmethod
    def get_first_non_zero(arr):
        try:
            return arr[arr != 0][0]
        except IndexError:
            return 0

    @staticmethod
    def get_first_non_zero_index(arr):
        try:
            return np.where(arr != 0)[0][0]
        except IndexError:
            return 3

    @staticmethod
    def get_last_zero_index(arr):
        try:
            return np.where(arr == 0)[0][-1]
        except IndexError:
            return 3

    def get_legal_moves_to(self, moveable_to):
        first_non_zero = self.first_non_zero
        n = first_non_zero.shape[0]
        if first_non_zero[moveable_to] == 0:
            return np.where((first_non_zero != 0) & (np.arange(n) != moveable_to))[0], moveable_to
        else:
            return np.where((first_non_zero == first_non_zero[moveable_to]) & (np.arange(n) != moveable_to))[0], moveable_to

    def swap(self, i, j):
        out = self.pos.copy()
        idx_from = (self.get_first_non_zero_index(self.pos[:, i]), i)
        idx_to = (self.get_last_zero_index(self.pos[:, j]), j)
        out[idx_from], out[idx_to] = out[idx_to], out[idx_from]
        return ColoredWater(out)

    def isgoal(self):
        return np.array_equiv(self.pos, self.pos[0])

    def __iter__(self):
        self.first_non_zero = np.apply_along_axis(self.get_first_non_zero, 0, self.pos)
        moveable_to = np.where(self.pos[0] == 0)[0]
        legal_moves = tuple(map(self.get_legal_moves_to, moveable_to))

        out = [self.swap(origin, target)
               for origins, target in legal_moves
               for origin in origins]   

        def number_of_full_stacks(pos):
            return np.sum(np.all((pos == [pos[0]]), axis=0))

        def fillings_of_stacks(game):
            pos = game.pos
            return number_of_full_stacks(pos), number_of_full_stacks(pos[1:]), number_of_full_stacks(pos[2:])

        return iter(sorted(out, key=fillings_of_stacks, reverse=True))

    def set_rep(self):
        return frozenset(map(tuple, self.pos.T))

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.pos)

    def solve(pos, depthFirst=False):
        queue = deque([pos])
        trail = {pos.set_rep(): None}
        solution = deque()
        load = queue.append if depthFirst else queue.appendleft

        while not pos.isgoal():
            for m in pos:
                if m.set_rep() in trail:
                    continue
                trail[m.set_rep()] = pos
                load(m)
            pos = queue.pop()

        while pos:
            solution.appendleft(pos)
            pos = trail[pos.set_rep()]

        return list(solution)
```

#### How to run it

First I run it on your example. In run with `depthFirst=True` it gives a solution in 117 moves in 376 ms. When I run it with `depthFirst=False` it gives an optimal solution in 55 moves in 9.42 s.

```
from ColoredWater import ColoredWater
import numpy as np

ColoredWater(np.array([[ 0,  1,  0,  5,  8,  9,  7,  4,  2,  8,  2,  5,  5, 10, 12],
                       [ 0,  2,  0,  6,  3, 10,  9,  7, 11,  3, 11, 12,  3,  6, 13],
                       [ 0,  3,  0,  7,  4,  2, 11, 11,  6, 12, 12, 13,  1, 13,  1],
                       [ 0,  4,  0,  5,  9,  9,  7,  6,  8,  8, 13,  1,  4, 10, 10]]))\
.solve(depthFirst=True)
```

I have also tested it on a "random" example:

```
def sort_zeros(x):
    return sorted(x, key=lambda x:x != 0)


n = 15

arr = np.broadcast_to(np.array([0,0,*range(n)]),(4,n+2)).copy()
np.random.shuffle(arr.reshape(-1))
arr = np.apply_along_axis(sort_zeros,0,arr)
print(ColoredWater(arr).solve(depthFirst=True))
```

Comment: Sorry for commenting on this after a long time has passed, but due to some life circumstances I couldn't get back to this until now. It's been 2 days now since I started reading and trying to understand your answer, but with the little to no experience I have with programming and numpy, I made 0 progress in these 2 days, so if I can get any help from you explaining it a bit, I would be very thankful.
Here is an example of where I get stuck trying to undersatnd: in the function get_legal_moves_to you define the variable first_non_zero and use it, and I have no idea if it's supposed to be an...

Comment: ...array or int, so I go to the function __iter__(self) where it's used to try and see what it is but couldn't understand still, it's a bit complicated for me, so if you could provide some comments on functions or something like that, it would be really helpful.

I know I'm asking for a lot so feel free to ignore this, i will try my best these next days to understand and i will get back to you on that if I get it finally

Comment: @MatsukaziIssy Hi, don't be sorry. I posted this here so somebody would read and comment on it. That was the intention :). Have you watched [the presentation of the Generic Puzzle Solver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_GP9OpZPUYc&t=435s) that this is based on? It is a really great presentation and a good place to start understanding. Also if you have specific questions feel free to ask me in the comments. I am afraid I don't feel like anticipating your questions and answering them in case you might not understand i.e. adding a lot of comments to my code.

Comment: When reading the function `get_legal_moves_to` and you wonder what the type of `first_non_zero` might be you could notice that I am calling `.shape` on it. That makes me pretty sure it's a `numpy array`.

Comment: hey @user2640045
thank you for answering, I will try to watch the lecture and try to give this more time and understand every detail, thank you so much for all your help

Comment: I do not think your solution is optimal with 55 moves. If you number the vials from 1 to 15 from left to right, here is a solution in 44 moves:

9-> 3  11-> 3  11-> 9  15->11  13-> 1   4-> 1  12-> 1  12->11  15->12   2->15  
 2-> 3  13-> 2  15->13  14->15   4->14   7-> 4   6-> 7   6->15   6-> 3   7-> 6  
 9-> 7  14-> 9  14->12  14->15   7->14   4-> 7   4-> 1  11-> 4  12->11  13->12  
 8->13   8-> 7   8->14   9-> 8   5-> 9   5-> 2   5->13   5-> 6  10-> 9  10-> 5  
10-> 4  10-> 9   2-> 5   2->13

My algorithm is described here:
http://kociemba.org/themen/waterball/colorsort.html

Answer (score 4):

You may take a look at [kociemba.org/themen/waterball/colorsort.html](http://kociemba.org/themen/waterball/colorsort.html)

The algorithm is explained here in detail and there also is a Github link to the code and a link to a win64 exe file.

Answer (score 0):

I got addicted me too in a colored ater sorting game also :))
Soon I reached a certain ( high) level, where the game creator added more colors. Until that it was 2 empty bottles and a few others with filled water.

I wanted to make a game, just like this and be a help button.
In order to implement that, I have to have a solution.

So, there is the backtracking ad the divide-et-impera recursion to get the solution.

But just like in chess, there is a kind of Greedy algorithm, without having the full solution ( I forgot the name)

Basically, any bottle has 2 states:
-has to be removed from that Initially most of them,

- has to be added to that ( initially the empty bottle or when you add a color.

Later, higher level, those empty bottles filled with 1 or 2 drops can become  a bottle, which has to be emptied! Example you have an empty bottle where you put 2x red on it. At a certain point you have to empty this to a bottle wich has Blue and Red (and you put other 2 red on in) in order to have an empty bottle. On that case the Blue it is blocked very well with 3x Red. :)

That game, which I play if you watch an add it allows to add +1 more empty bottles. That will make the game a lot easier. And if toy watch another add you get another empty bottle ( so in total 4 empty). On that case "the problem can be solved sometimes by an 5 years old child, sometimes :)
The conclusion from this: adding empty bottles will maske the game solve easier.

Also from Rubik cube, if you disassembly the cube and turn 1 square out, the Rubik cube will be impossible to solve with rotations. From this the conclusion is: if you just add randomly generated colors from bottles it may be impossible to solve.

As a game creator I should start from correctly filled bottles and do the random mixing with 2 empty bottles to have an itial state which can be solved for sure.

The Greedy algo to solve the problem ( the Greedy is not the best, neither guarantee result) is : take the most number of top colors: 3 red, 2 green, 1-1- other. I will take the most number: red and start to fill the empty bottle with red. If I fail, I try to remember and fill with the other 2 colors.

Also if is Red what I should take, because 2x on top, but also 2x red on the bottom, than I don't take the red.
Usually I don't take the color, which has the most at bottom.

When we learn the recursion, than we learn that there is a "decission tree", for these games and solutions. You must walk that tree: pre-order, in-order, post-order. Of course it is easier for me to write a software than run it in my head :)

So, "the shortest path to solve colored water sorting games" - you mean less move.
That is for absolutely sure is adding more empty bottles.
and "the shortest" -it means you have all correct solutions and you choose that one, which meats a criteria ( less move) => you have to generate all of the solutions, than is backtracking.
The complexity of backtracking it is not O(n) - but a lot worse ( exponential or so)

So adding more colors will make it a lot harder, a looooooot!, just try it!

Answer (score 0):

there is somthing previous answer **doesn't cover**.

when you empty a vial to another all the same color liquid goes to the second vial.

here is the new swap function code that I wrote:

```
def swap(self, i, j):
        out = self.pos.copy()
        f_row,f_col = (self.get_first_non_zero_index(self.pos[:, i]), i)
        t_row,t_col = (self.get_last_zero_index(self.pos[:, j]), j)
        while f_row<len(self.pos):
            out[f_row][f_col], out[t_row][t_col] = out[t_row][t_col], out[f_row][f_col]
            if f_row + 1 < len(self.pos):
                if self.pos[f_row + 1][f_col] == self.pos[f_row][f_col]:
                    f_row+=1
                    t_row-=1
                    if t_row <0:
                        break
                else:
                    break
            else:
                break
        return ColoredWater(out)
```